# Help with tableof package: tagged TOCs outside the main TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using `tableof` to create two additional TOCs for tagged sections.
In the included MWE I end up with the main TOC, but I've only been able to add the two tagged TOCs in their own sections, which show up in the main TOC as well:

[image]

My goal is to have them:

- in separate pages
- with a custom title
- listing the chapter title as well (if the topic is present in there)
- not showing in the main TOC.

Mockup as follows:

[image]

Do you think it is possible?
Thank you for any suggestion you're able to provide!

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
    numbers=endperiod,
    oneside
]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tableof}

% ---------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\section{Table of A Content}
\tableof{a}

\section{Table of B Content}
\tableof{b}

\section{Introduction}

something

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}
\toftagthis{a}
\section{Topic A}
something
\toftagthis{a}
\section{Topic A}
something
\toftagthis{b}
\section{Topic B}
something

\chapter{Second}
\toftagthis{b}
\section{Topic B}
something
\toftagthis{b}
\section{Topic B}
something
\toftagthis{a}
\section{Topic A}
something

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you can use `\section*` rather than `\section` to get section headings that are neither numbered nor listed in the TOC. For a `book`ish class, you'll want `\chapter*`, though. Also, you can use `\newpage` to start a new page:

````
\documentclass[
    numbers=endperiod,
    oneside
]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tableof}

% ---------------------------
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter*{Table of A Content}
\tableof{a}
\newpage
\chapter*{Table of B Content}
\tableof{b}
\newpage
\section{Introduction}

something

\mainmatter

\chapter{First}
\toftagthis{a}
\section{Topic A}
something
\toftagthis{a}
\section{Topic A}
something
\toftagthis{b}
\section{Topic B}
something

\chapter{Second}
\toftagthis{b}
\section{Topic B}
something
\toftagthis{b}
\section{Topic B}
something
\toftagthis{a}
\section{Topic A}
something

\end{document}```
````

Comment: Great, much appreciated, thanks! This checks 3 out of 4 items in the list, there's only to figure out how to add the chapters in the tagged TOCs.

Comment: You're welcome! Re: the last item on your list, I'm not familiar with `tableof`, but there might be an option to automatically add higher-level TOC items. Or you could tag the `\chapter`s manually, though I'd only consider that an acceptable solution in a small document.